# svn export using network

Tags: svn, bash

im writing a bash script to update the WWW ROOT on production server from SVN

basically i've a working copy of the whole codebase outside the webroot. first i will do an `svn update` to get the latest version.

afterwards. i will use `svn export` to export it to another folder, then remove some unwanted files from this folder and then udpate the WWW root.

the problem is that the process is very slow coz the production server accesses the SVN server over the internet.  `SVN EXPORT` command downloads all the codebase which is really time-consuming.

is there any way that I can force the `SVN EXPORT` command to not to use the network? I have checked out BASE and HEAD revisions but the problem is: in that case if i want to revert then first i will have to revert my working copy and then perform another export `SVN EXPORT -r BASE` which would mean that production will be down while the working copy is updated to the older revision.

PS: I dont wan to use WWW ROOT as my SVN working copy.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the following line:

```
svn export path/to/local/wc desired/path
```